# Wizzair blocks traffic from EC2 and OVH VPS even if I use a proxy

Tags: web-scraping, proxy, cloud, virtual-machine, ovh

I wanted to test my webscraping app on cloud environment. At first I have tried EC2 machine, but I realised that wizzair blocks outbound traffic from all AWS's IP address range.

Next I have tried OVH [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) and there was the same issue. Next I have added paid proxy to my client and well... It works from my local machine, but when I try to run it on OVH's VPS I still have access denied. Other websites are reachable, so it is not machine's thing.

Do you maybe have more ideas how could I avoid these restrictions? How is it possible wizzair detects traffic from the cloud when I use a proxy? I've been tearing my hair out.

Comment: What is "wizzair"? Presumably not [the airline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizz_Air)?

Comment: What is OVH? The [French cloud computing company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OVHcloud)?